# getOpenFileName Разваливаеться что делать

Tags: qt

Разваливается если нажать "кнопку закрытия "

```
 QFileDialog dlg(this);
 QString D_path = "C:/WORK/";
 QString D_format = "bin";
 QString isRead;
 isRead  = dlg.getOpenFileName(this,trUtf8("Открываем  данные зарегистрированные осциллографом"),D_path,trUtf8("DUMP(*.%1)").arg(D_format));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо просто добавить проверку на заполненность файла .

```
  isRead  = dlg.getOpenFileName(this,trUtf8("Открываем  данные зарегистрированные осциллографом"),D_path,trUtf8("DUMP(*.%1)").arg(D_format));
if(isRead.isEmpty())
 { 
     return;
 }
```

Я понимаю что вопрос тривиальный но ,меня он занял. вот официальный ответ на мой вопрос . 
Warning: Do not delete parent during the execution of the dialog. If you want to do this, you should create the dialog yourself using one of the QFileDialog constructors.

Answer (score 1):

Я приведу [пример](https://github.com/gil9red/NotesManager/blob/90864c80674bdd88540eed9147b9c58d34fc355b/Note/RichTextNote.cpp#L683) использования и оформления:

```
const QString & fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName( this );
if ( fileName.isEmpty() )
    return;

QFile file( fileName );
if ( !file.open( QIODevice::ReadOnly ) )
    return;

QTextStream out( &file );
out.setCodec( "utf8" );

setText( out.readAll() );
```

Используется в функции (о чем намекает `return`), иначе меняем проверку и работу с `if` на противоположную:

```
const QString & fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName( this );
if ( !fileName.isEmpty() ) {

    QFile file( fileName );
    if ( file.open( QIODevice::ReadOnly ) ) {
        QTextStream out( &file );
        out.setCodec( "utf8" );

        setText( out.readAll() );
    }
}
```